# RavenDB - Query specific type in mixed collections

Tags: ravendb

A few weeks ago I asked if it was possible to have multiple types in one 'collection' in raven, and I have loved it. But now I am getting to writing some indexes/queries, and am running into a problem..

I did not realize that this meant the types would all be treated as the same thing. I thought the "collection" was only a string that was used for the RavenDB Management Studio. So ... in this situation..

`class Prototypes : { // ... }`

Goes into "items" collection with identity pattern **items/prototypes/#**

`class Items : { // ... }`

Goes into "items" collection with identity pattern **items/#**

`class Schemas : { // ... }`

Goes into "items" collection with identity pattern **items/##/schemas/##**

So if I do ...

```
var prototypes = RavenSession.Query<Prototype>().ToArray();
```

I get all of the Items and Schemas too. Is there any way to be specific about the type of things I want back from an index/query?

The initial desire to group them into one collection was merely to keep things tidy and not have a lot of disparate collections. I did not realize at the time that this was going to happen, since I believed it was class name that was important for queries, not collection name.

Answer (score 0):

You should only be getting back `Prototype` items from that query.  When you supply a type to a dynamic query, the index that is built is already filtering results to that type.  It filters using the `Raven-Entity-Name` metadata, and this all happens rather magically in the background.  You shouldn't have to think about it too much.

Are you actually getting back `Items` and `Schemas` types from this query?  You shouldn't be.

BTW - these are very strange names for entities.  Usually one works with more specific classes such as `Customer` or `BlogPost`.  Having classes like `Prototypes`, `Items`, `Schemas` seems rather strange unless you are building something *very generic* and these are relevant to your domain.

Comment: They are, indeed, extremely generic relative to the domain. Items implement multiple prototypes, which are underlying concepts for them. (For example, all Weapons are not Swords, but all weapons ARE weapons. Sword and Weapon are prototypes, and a "Specific" sword inherits features from both). Schemas are instances of items (Two characters might have different instances of the same item, and customize them in some way)

Comment: Yes, I am getting back Items and Schemas, because they are all in the same collection. Ayende told me that it wasn't possible to do what I was trying, so I guess I just go back to different collections. You can see the entire topic here : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ravendb/gG2syQjssQw

Comment: So let us assume a two handed sword... `Special Two-Hand Sword`. This is `items/12`, and it has the full data for prototypes `Sword`, `Two-Hand Weapon`, and `Weapon` in it. Two characters get this item. They have `items/12/schemas/1` and `items/12/schemas/2`. This allows them to be independent items, but mechanically can be treated as the same - and new instances can be created in the future.

Comment: This is important to our design because we want to be able to make global behaviors based on simpler prototypes. (Such as Two-Hand Weapons having an innate bonus to damage in the game). We were going to do this with a simple field, but as we continued to evolve the concept we learned we wanted to be a bit more diverse with it (such as adding actual statistics to prototypes, and allowing them to be inherited or suppressed by parents). So in the end we determined that diving it up like this was the best result, because of how Raven lets us store entire documents in the parents.